# How to only accept date inputs of more than 18 years ago in Django

Tags: django, forms, datetime, datefield

I have a form that allows users to update their birthday on their profile. I want it to only be valid if the user is at least 18 years of age. Here's what I've tried:

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    birthday = models.DateField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime
from .models import Profile

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    def clean_birthday(self):
        dob = self.cleaned_data['birthday']
        age = (datetime.now() - dob).days / 365
        if age < 18:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must be at least 18 years old')
        return dob

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('birthday',)
```

Upon submit I am getting the TypeError `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'`

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def update_my_profile_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return redirect('users:my_profile')
```

Can somebody please explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward: It says that you're using types that aren't compatible for subtraction (operand `-`): You're trying to subtract a `date` (`dob`) from a `datetime` (`datetime.now()`). Python doesn't allow you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line:
`age = (datetime.now() - dob).days / 365`

`datetime.now()` -> returns a `datetime`
`dob` -> is a `date`

So, you are subtracting two different data types!

```
from datetime import date
date.today()
```

This will return only the date, and you can use it in place of datetime.now()

Comment: Great, that worked! Thanks. Although I now have a new problem. If I submit a date less than 18 years from today it simply does not display the date, rather than invalidate the form as I'd hoped

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with Django. I answered this as it was a general python error!